# Migration Table for Foreign Key Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I'm facing problem when add foreign key and doing php artisan migrate : fresh

There is error

```
("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id_rso'")
```

This  is my migration table :

```html
public function up()
    {   
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('dso', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id_dso',30);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_rso');
            $table->foreignId('id_rso')->constrained('rso');
            $table->smallInteger('id_focus');
            $table->smallInteger('id_wilayah');
            $table->smallInteger('id_grup_wilayah');
            $table->string('nama_dso',50);
            $table->string('created_by',50)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_date',$precision = 0);
            $table->string('modified_by',50)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('modified_date',$precision = 0)->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->boolean('status')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary('id_dso');
        });
    }
```

I'm using mysql for database and laravel 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_rso');
$table->foreignId('id_rso')->constrained('rso');
```

Instead of this, just write:

```
$table->foreignId('id_rso')->constrained('rso');
```

Comment: still an error `errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")`

Comment: I was tried that, any idea what this happen

Comment: Make sure foreign key column and referenced column types are same. ```id_rso``` is unsignedBigInteger. So you should change referenced column to unsignedBigInteger, then the foreign key creation will workperfectly.

Comment: Yes there are same.
This mean I'm must used unsignedBigInteger?

Comment: Okey, why do you create foreign key relation like this?


$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: yeah, it works, I doing this 
`$table->string('id_rso',30);` and `$table->foreign('id_rso')->references('id_rso')->on('rso');`

Comment: if using `unsignedBigInteger`will be error. Anyway thank you for your help